# Collecting geometries and selecting attribute-value using QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry

In QGIS, I have a polygon-layer with communes. Some communes consist of different parts (exclaves). I want to merge all parts of the same communes to one object. How is it possible to define which values from the attribute-table (inhabitants) is collected as the attribute-value of the new multi-polygon? Some parts of my input layer have NULL-values - I want to avoid them and always take the value that is not NULL, but QGIS seems to select always the first value.

In the attribute-table, the no. of inhabitants is specified only in the main polygon (center of commune), not in the exclave (often actuylla uninhabited). In a schematic way, here is how my data looks like - part 2 is exclave of part 1, part 3 exclave of part 4:

part 1 : commune-id 435 : inhabitants: 2853
part 2 : commune-id 435 : inhabitants: NULL
part 3 : commune-id 729 : inhabitants: NULL
part 4 : commune-id 729 : inhabitants: 3517

I now perform `select geometries` to merge all parts that belong to the same political body (commune) to one object, thus I create multipolygons, based on a field "commune-id". Works well, but not all values for inhabitants in the resulting layer are the correct ones. Merging the object above based on commune-id, I get:

part new_a : commune-id 435 : inhabitants: 2853
part new_b : commune-id 729 : inhabitants: NULL

In the second case, the no. of inhabitants should be 3517, not NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **Aggregate** tool (in `Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry`).

[image]

1. Group by your `commune-id` (this `Group by` will also **collect** geometries in the same group).
2. Choose `first_value` as aggregate function for the `commune-id` field.
3. Choose `sum` for the `inhabitants`.